# locate Eclipse's Preferences menu item programmatically in OS X

Tags: eclipse

In Windows/Linux, I use WorkbenchWindow.getMenuManager() to navigate to the Windows menu and locate the Preferences menu item. In OS X, the Preferences menu item is located in Eclipse’s application pulldown menu. What is the API to locate the Preference item in OS X? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to find the menu item? If you just want to show the preferences dialog there is a separate API for that.

Comment: we have some automated UI testcases. They are supposed to locate the Preference menu item and click it. In Windows/Linux, we call WorkbenchWindow.getMenuManager().getMenu to locate the Windows menu and then call Menu.getItems() to locate the Preferences item. This returns a MenuItem that we send a SWT.Selection event to. We want to do the same thing in OS X if possible.

Comment: If we cannot use the old approach for this, what is the API to show the Preference dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The actions for Preferences (and Help About and Quit) are still added in the normal places on the Mac but the action is marked as not visible (code is in `WorkbenchActionBuilder`).

The Mac only code `CocoaUIHandler` sets up the Mac only menu items, it just searches for the hidden actions when the action is invoked.

So you may not need to do anything special for the Mac.

Note: `WorkbenchWindow` is an internal class so it isn't part of the official API, this is probably not a concern for testing code (it is very substantially different between Eclipse 3.x and 4.x).

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you provide an example how this can be done?

Comment: What I am saying is I don't think you have to do anything different.

Comment: WorkbenchWindow.getMenuManager() only returns the menus File, Edit, Help etc. However, it does not include the application menu.

Comment: Yes, but the Preferences item is still under the Window menu but marked as not visible, you should still be able to find it.

Comment: Menu.getItems() for the Window menu returns items that are visible on the menu. However, it does not include the Preference item. I think I have to change the code to use WorkbenchWindow.getMenuManager().findMenuUsingPath("Windows").getItems() that returns all visible and non-visible items.